# Typo3 jQuery OnClick Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, typo3, typo3-extensions

i need some help for my fresh installed Typo3 Website.

I want to set new Values within my DataBase via jQuery onClick Event.
So i guess i need to make use of this class: **TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool**.
Can someone Guide me how i can make use of this class within JavaScript.

I already tried the following, but i can't get it to work

```
define(['jquery', 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool'], function($, conPool) {

   if(conPool.foo == 'bar'){
      conPool.init();
   }
});
```

[Typo3 source](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/JavaScript/RequireJS/Dependency/Index.html)

I appreciating any Help. Thanks

Comment: Please first try to understand the difference between client (browser, JS) and server (TYPO3, PHP). You cannot mix these like this, instead you'll need to perform HTTP requests in JavaScript (fetch/AJAX) to talk to TYPO3. You can find various questions about this on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @MathiasBrodala 
Thanks for the reply. I think i explained it the wrong way.

Comment: You'd need an AJAX site that is taking JavaScript arguments to a PHP-class and delivers the requested variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your frontend should not be allowed to communicate directly with the database of your TYPO3 instance.
If you allow it anyone can inspect your javascript and get credentials to access your database - and do anything they like. :(

The correct way is a server request with the data you want to change.
then some PHP can compute the data (verify, adapt, ...) and change the value in the database (as PHP has the local credentials to access the database). Then it's up to you to give a notice in the front end if that operation was successful or not.
Such a server-request could be a complete page request, but a simple AJAX-call would be enough. Though you does not need to rebuild the complete page. From the Return of that AJAX request you can show only a notice about failure or success as a flash-message or similar.